# Git command in Powershell: "git log $strVar" does not work

Tags: powershell, command-line, parameters, command-line-arguments

In PowerShell the `git` command below doesn't work

```
$strVar = "--graph --oneline"
git log $strVar
```

It returns: `fatal: unrecognized argument: --graph --oneline`. Why doesn't it work?

I noticed that the space has something to do with the my problem because this will work:

```
git log "--oneline"
```

But this doesn't work:

```
git log "--oneline "
```

Comment: It's definitely a powershell thing. Unix-style shells will do word splitting on unquoted arguments here.

Comment: I think so too. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: No, I haven't used Powershell. I did some google searching and there's a whole bunch of rules about splitting but I don't *have* Powershell either and cannot experiment with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log "--oneline "` doesn't work because git receives `--oneline`  with a trailing space as a single argument. Same to your `git log $strVar` where git receives `$strVar` as a parameter. PowerShell works on objects and not strings so in PowerShell you typically don't save parameters in a string like that and use arrays instead, then run the command with the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-)

```
$params = "--graph", "--oneline" # Or '@("--graph", "--oneline")'
# '@()' denotes an array, '+' is an array concatenation
& git (@("log") + $params)
# Alternative way, the comma operator converts the operand to array
& git (,"log" + $params)
```

You can also use [Invoke-Expression](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.2) for parameters in a single string, but only when the whole command line is simple because if there are special characters then you'll need some escaping

```
$params = "--graph --oneline"
Invoke-Expression ("git log " + $params)
iex "git log $params" # Alias of Invoke-Expression
```

Another solution is to use [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2)

```
Start-Process -FilePath git -ArgumentList (@("log") + $params)
saps git (,"log" + $params) # Alias
```

Comment: This really helped me out, thanks you so much!